# Non-Causal time-series filtering techniques for standard noise with unkown variance. (EM vs. weiner vs. kalman)

Tags: expectation-maximization, noise

This is a quick question about filtering stored time-series data using kalman/weiner filtering techniques or expectation maximization. I'm just hoping to fix some confusion about questioning performance (and which would be worth implementing given the complexity of each).

**EM** is the most general of the techniques, and is a framework to allow you to essentially solve for MAP or MLE estimates of constant unkown parameters in hierarchical models with latent/hidden variables.

**weiner filtering** is an online filtering (and thus offline as well) technique to recover a filtered signal disturbed by guassian noise. unlike EM, It has no hidden states.

**kalman filter** is an online (and offline) techniique much like weiner filtering except that the inference is on the hidden states of a dynamic system using iterative regression from measured outputs.

Thoughts: an often caveat in my experience with using the Kalman Filter, which is generally considered an improvement on the Wieiner Filter, is that you pretty much need to know the variance or covariance of the noise variables in both the states and observations. There are estimation algorithms like the robbin's monroe algorithm, which seem to work, although I've had issues applying them to kalman filters ( however perhaps that has just been my misunderstanding of how to use the algorithm).

Question: Would **EM** using only signal $Y_k$, assuming a latent Gaussian Noise $ \epsilon_k \sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma)$, with $\sigma$ unkown, added to the true signal $X_k$, perform better or worse than a Weiner Filter using the Robbins Monroe algorithm or better.

*Assuming operating on just static observed data to find* $X_k$: All three algorithms would perform roughly equivalent, since the kalman filter reduces to the Weiner filter if no hidden states variables being estimated. EM would perform the same but would be more computationally expensive.

In an entirely different scenario, in which $X_k$ were the output of some dynamic process, then Wieiner filtering becomes the worst performing of the three. My thoughts were that the kalman and EM algorithms would perform the same, and the weiner filter would suffer because it is not inferring the true underlying state, as the kalman filter and EM are. Weiner Filtering is an input-2-output or "black box" method. The KF would be the best choice due to the computational complexity and generality of EM. And that essentially, the kalman filter would be considered an efficient and online implementation of EM algorithm in this particular situation.

Any thoughts. Is My thinking correct?